# how to call a function of c++ file in .m file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a header file `test.h`

```
 #ifndef __visibilty_test__test__

 #define __visibilty_test__test__

 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test{

public:

    void print(string s);
};

 #endif
```

and `test.mm`

```
 #include "test.h"

using namespace std;


void test:: print(string s){

    cout << s << endl;

}
```

now I want to call print function in my `AppDelegate.m` file in an iOS Application. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `test.mm` should be called `test.cpp` as it's pure C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem when #import C++ Header File in iPhone/iPad Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890552/problem-when-import-c-header-file-in-iphone-ipad-project)

Answer (score 2):

1. Rename `AppDelegate.m` to `AppDelegate.mm`.
2. Call the method as you would in C++:

   ```
   test t;
   t.print("Hello");
   ```

Comment: (Do not use lists, neither numbered nor bullets, combined with code formatting. SO screws it up.)

Comment: Thanks Sir, but now i am getting this error "iostream" file not found"

Answer (score 0):

Your object:

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 class test
 {
     public:
         void print(string s)
         {
             cout << s << endl;
         }
 };
```

call from mm file

```
test *t = new test;
t->print("hello");
```